# I'm trying to beautify an URL in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Since I have finished my project, just unable to understand the url beautifying. Suppose this is my url:

```
localhost/wowwaylabs/trunk/mpi_v1/index.php?r=products/index&catId=1
```

Where products is a controller and index is a action of that controller. catId is the parameter I am passing through the url. I need to beautify the url to

```
localhost/wowwaylabs/trunk/mpi_v1/this-is-india-1
```

where 1 is the catId I'm passing through.

Comment: what is `this-is-india` is that the name of the category?

Answer (score 2):

For making url beautiful, you need to add following lines of code in .htaccess file which should be in the root folder of your project:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

It will keep your url without ?r.

Now uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format(in protected/config/main.php)

```
/*
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
  ),
),
*/
```

Then add `'showScriptName'=>false,` in 'urlManager' of same file. It will remove index.php from the url.

For more check these links:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

http://www.sniptrichint.com/tip-of-the-day/beautiful-url-in-yii-without-index/

I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `this-is-india` is a variable or arbitrary length (i.e. category name that may vary wildy in length or syntax, as Pitchinnate suggests in the comments) then you can do this purely using url manager with no need to edit your htaccess like so:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    ...
    'rules'=>array(
        '<catName:[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+>-<catId:\d+>'=>'products/index',
        ...
    ),
    ...
),
```

This will take any combination of characters with a number at the end and use the number at the end as the `catId`, for example:

```
localhost/wowwaylabs/trunk/mpi_v1/this-is-india-1
```

Will resolve to

```
localhost/wowwaylabs/trunk/mpi_v1/index.php?r=products/index&catId=1&catName=this-is-india
```

Similarly;

```
localhost/wowwaylabs/trunk/mpi_v1/this-is-another-title-or-category-or-whatever-999
```

will resolve to:

```
localhost/wowwaylabs/trunk/mpi_v1/index.php?r=products/index&catId=999&catName=this-is-another-title-or-category-or-whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Through htaccess :)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$/? index.php?r=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

`localhost/wowwaylabs/trunk/mpi_v1/products/index/&catId=1`

Comment: Is there a way to do that using the url manager. Else can you just give me explaination on this?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with Yii. But the `htaccess` file is what handles the requests that come in through apache. The first two lines turn on URL rewriting. The next two say to only run the rewrite if the file doesn't actually exists and the third is a regex matching anything to `index.php?r=`

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Yii's URL Manager (if not follow Workonphp's instructions to turn it on) try creating a rule and add it at the top of the rules that looks like this:

```
'<category_id:\w+>' => 'products/index',
```

What is this will do, is if only one parameter (i.e. category name and id)  is passed in the url and it is a string/word (:\w+ specifies this) not an number (:\d+) it will default to the products controller and the index action. It will then pass `$category_id` as a variable into the controller. You will then need to modify that action to pull the id out of the string like so:

```
public function actionIndex($category_id) {
    $pieces = explode('-',$category_id);
    $cat_id = end($pieces); //actual category id seperated from name
    //...rest of code for this function
}
```